# How to create dynamic select option in laravel?

Tags: ajax, laravel

I want to generate a list on items in a drop down based on a previous choice from another select. All items ar in the database.

Here is what I did:

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).on('change', '#province_name', function() {
        var province_id = $(this).val();
        var div = $(this).parent();
        var op = " ";
        $.ajax({
            type: 'get',
            url: '{!!URL::to('admin/findIDProvince')!!}',
            data: {'id':province_id},
            success: function(data){
                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
                    op += '<option value="'+data[i].id+'">'+data[i].city_name+'</option>';
                }
                div.find('#city_name').html(" ");
                div.find('#city_name').append(op);
            },
            error: function(){
                console.log('success');
            },
        });
    });
});
```

Routes (web.php):

```
Route::namespace('Admin')->prefix('admin')->middleware('auth')->group(function (){
    $this->get('/findIDProvince', 'SchoolsListController@findIDProvince');
});
```

Controller (Admin/SchoolsListController.php):

```
public function findIDProvince(Request $request)
    {
        $data = City::select('city_name', 'id')->where('province_id', $request->id)->take(100)->get();
        return response()->json($data);
    }
```

HTML (view.blade.php)

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-md-3" for="province_name">province_name</label>
    <div class="col-md-9">
        <select id="province_name" name="province_name" class="form-control col-md-12" required>
            @foreach($province_names as $province_name)
                <option value="{{ $province_name->id }}">{{ $province_name->province_name }}</option>
            @endforeach
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-md-3" for="city_name">city_name</label>
    <div class="col-md-9">
        <select id="city_name" name="city_name" class="form-control col-md-12" required>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `<select id="city_name" ...` is not targetable via `$("#city")`; that's a typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using

```
div.find('#city').html(" ");
div.find('#city').append(op);
```

but in your blade you have

`id = city_name`

Use:

```
div.find('#city_name').html(" ");
div.find('#city_name').append(op);
```